# What is the compatible version of this query for NDB?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Maybe it's wrong but I always use this query for my app:

```
cme_only = Comput.all().filter('__key__ =', cid.key())
```

What is the compatible version of this query for NDB?
The Metadata queries are very different..

**edit**:
cid is an entity and cme_only is an iterable that I'm sure has only one value

```
cid = Comput.get_by_id(int(self.request.get('id')))
cme_only = Comput.all().filter('__key__ =', cid.key())
```

and then in template:

```
{{ for Comput in cme_only }}
```

I do not like it but it was enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `cid` is your entity then you could do that:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
cme_only = ndb.Key(Comput, cid.key.id()).get()
```

But this will return you basically the same entity that you start with, the `cid`, But in general this is one way of querying by key.

You can check more on how to [construct keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Constructors) in the docs.

Comment: what is `cid`? if its an ndb model than it should be `cid.key`... without calling it.

Comment: @aschmid00 That's what I asume.. let's wait from the OP and I will change it accordingly..

Comment: cid is an entity `cid = Comput.get_by_id(int(self.request.get('id')))`

Comment: If cid is an NDB entity (ndb.Model subclass instance) then cid.key is a Key object and ndb.Key(Comput, cid.key) is nonsense -- the second argument to ndb.Key() must be an int or a string, not another Key.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum True.. Forgot the id() when I was changing it.. but still it doesn't make sense to use that when you have already the cid as an NDB entity..

Answer (score 7):

There's no need for metadata queries.  The NDB way to spell a query on `__key__` is as follows:

```
ModelClass.query(ModelClass._key == key_value)
```

That is, just like querying for property foo is done by filtering on `ModelClass.foo == value`, `ModelClass._key` is a pseudo-property representing the key.

The other posters are correct that if you just one a single entity given its full key, using the `get()` method on the Key object is better (faster and cheaper).  Also, if e is an entity (model instance), in NDB, the key is not `e.key()` but `e.key` (or `e._key` -- yes, that's the same _key attribute I mentioned in above, it works as a class attribute and as an instance attribute).

And indeed, if you have a urlsafe key (e.g. `'agFfcg4LEghFbXBsb3llZRgDDA'`) the way to turn it into a Key object is `ndb.Key(urlsafe='agFfcg4LEghFbXBsb3llZRgDDA')`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Guido, I will endeavor to complete the transition to ndb.